# Object reference required for a non-static field

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Excel1.Program.GetAllTemplateNames(string, string)"  I know this is pretty silly but I am quite new to C# and could do with some assistance in debugging this code. Is it even possible to call a static function from a Main function? Am having these doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
      GetAllTemplateNames(strParam1, strRetVal);
```

to

```
      new Program().GetAllTemplateNames(strParam1, strRetVal);
```

or make the method static.

Answer (score 4):

Since `ProcessInput` is static you cannot call the instance(non-static) method `GetAllTemplateNames` from there without having an instance of this class (`Program`).

So you either need to make `GetAllTemplateNames` also static or you need to make `ProcessInput` non-static. I would choose the second option since `GetAllTemplateNames` needs to access some instance variables which is impossible when it's static.

So change the signature of `ProcessInput` in the following way(note the omited `static`):

```
public void ProcessInput(String strRetVal, String strFunctionName, /*String strParamCount,*/ String strParam1, String strParam2, String strParam3, String strParam4)
```

now you also need to change the call of this method in `main` to:

```
var p = new Program();  // create an instance
p.ProcessInput(strRetVal, strFunctionName, /*strParamCount,*/ strParam1, strParam2, strParam3, strParam4);
```

[MSDN: static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should make the `GetAllTemplateNames` method `static` if you want to be able to call it from other static methods without an instance of a class:

```
public static void GetAllTemplateNames(String strParam, String strRetVal)
```

This also means that the fields that this method uses (`templateClient` and `taskClient` must also be static)

or another possibility is to create an instance of the containing class:

```
new Program().GetAllTemplateNames(strParam1, strRetVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is occurring on the line `GetAllTemplateNames(strParam1, strRetVal);`, and any other calls to `GetAllTemplateNames()` or `ReturnAllTemplateNames()`.

These methods are not static, yet you are calling them from a static method! You'll need to make them static, or create an instance of their containing class in order to call them from a static method like `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The main function is static, that's why you can call ProcessInput. However, you can't call a non-static function from a static one : GetAllTemplateNames has to be a static function.